# Fibonacci sequence calculation in Python

Tags: python, fibonacci

I tried to do a function that builds the Fibonacci series but when I try to check the calculation comes out wrong

```
def fibo(n):
    i=1
    j=1
    for n in range(1,n):
        j=j+i
        i=j+i
    return i+j
n=input('Enter number:')
print(fibo(int(n)))
```

Comment: How do you know it is wrong? Can you update your question with some sample sessions to show what is happening?

Comment: Walk through your code on paper for n= 2 and compute what is returned.  Is it correct?, if not where did you go wrong?

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-program-for-fibonacci-numbers-2/

Comment: It looks like you are doing 2 steps per iteration. try putting some print lines within your loop to see what is going on

Answer (score 1):

```
i, j = 1, 1
for _ in range(n):
    j = j + i
    i = j + i
```

This is not the fibonacci sequence. Instead, try:

```
i, j = 1, 1
for _ in range(n):
    i, j = j, i+j
```

Comment: N.B. that this will still not return the nth fib number. Assuming you're returning the value of j, you're getting the n+2 fib number (since the initial values of i and j are the 0th and 1st values).